# How some applications does not allow administrator user to close them?

Tags: windows, security, winapi

I have `"Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10"` on my windows. In my place, it has some server application too and if you want to close the application, you must enter the password which is determined in server side.

By the way, if you wanted to close the application process (`avp.exe`) by `Task Manager` or `Resource Monitor`, (even if you were administrator of current PC and you ran these applications as an Administrator), system tells that you does not have access to do it. `Task Manager` alerts:

```
The Operation could not be completed.
Access is denied.
```

And `Resource Monitor` informs:

```
When attempting to execute the command, the following system error occurred:
Access is denied.
```

So Why? Is there any access level in windows higher than system administrator? If Yes, what is it and who grants it? And if No, What is this error? Does Kaspersky uses any special idea? What is that idea?

And finally, can we add this feature to our applications too?

Comment: I faced this problem once too. It is ridiculous that an application can restrict administrators accessibilities.

Comment: Usually by denying PROCESS_TERMINATE permission, Process Explorer will show this.

Answer (score 7):

> I have "Kaspersky Endpoint Security 10" on my windows.

I'm so sorry.

> Is there any access level in windows higher than system administrator?

Yes, sort of. There is SYSTEM, which represents the local machine itself and isn't a real user you can log in as. However, as an Administrator you have the ability to set services and tasks up to run as SYSTEM (see eg PsExec for how to use this to get a system shell) and change the permissions on files and processes belonging to SYSTEM, so there isn't actually a meaningful security boundary here.

Whilst you can get terminate permission back from administrator, this is unlikely to be the only trick Kaspersky has up its sleeve. There is an ongoing arms race between malware and antivirus authors(*) each trying to automate removing the other, so it would common to see eg persistent re-spawning preventing you from really getting rid of the process.

(* in as much as there is any concrete difference these days, when AV may itself be spyware...)

> And finally, can we add this feature to our applications too?

Please, no! This only irritates users and does not provide any real enforceable security.

Comment: If Task Manager is running in administrator mode, it automatically uses debug privilege to bypass process permissions.  So it isn't just that Kaspersky has set itself an ACL that denies access to administrators, there must be a kernel-mode component in play.